# on duplicate key mysql (update/insert)?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to check when using

> INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY

whether if an INSERT or an UPDATE performed in the current query?

Thanks

Comment: Best way is to write trigger on table for Insert/Update operation.

Comment: No.  Because both could occur.